# Split rich text into a list including the richtext code

Tags: c#, parsing, richtext

I'm trying to find a way to split this properly but until now I bump into many issues.

using `string.split / string.substring, string.indexof, string.replace` and so on.

here is a sample string that needs to be split into a list.

```
We are <b><i>very</i></b><b>a</b>mused!\nThank you.
```

and the result in the list should be in this order :

```
0: We
1: are
2: <b>
3: <i>
4: very
5: </i>
6: </b>
7: <b>
8: a
9: </b>
10: mused!
11: \n
12: Thank
13: you.
```

So what i am trying to do is this :

```
splitStart = baseString.Value.Split(' ');
foreach (string part in splitStart)
{
    if (part.Contains("<"))
    {
        // get the parts <b>  <i>  <size>  <color>  </b>  </i>  </size> </color> \n
        textlist.Add(part); // add each part to list
    }
    else
    {
        textlist.Add(part);
        Debug.Log(part);
    }
}
```

I tried things like

```
contains("<n>")
replace "<n>" "" and add "<n>" to array
```

but that can break the sequence.

Edit :
I forgot to say that this is for c#

Comment: seems like quite a handy situation of defining a parser. The rules need to be clear in the first place for this. If you split it based on a space `" "`, the tags seem all inked into a single chain to me. Then `<` needs to find a matching `>` to pull out the substring into the final list. Then `!` and the `\nT` needs a special handling again.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need some pre-processing of characters using some html parser like [jsoup](https://jsoup.org/) or tree structure algorithm.

It's one option to make this case with Jsoup library.

***1. Java version***

First, prepare word list from the html tags.

```
final List<String> wordList = new ArrayList<String>();
```

then, traverse the html contents using Jsoup's NodeVisitor class.

```
doc.body().traverse(
            new NodeVisitor(){

                @Override
                public void head(Node arg0, int arg1) {
                    if(arg1 == 1)
                    {
                        String value = arg0.outerHtml();
                        if(!wordList.contains(value))
                            wordList.add(arg0.outerHtml());
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void tail(Node arg0, int arg1) {

                }
            }
        );
```

Finally, the code is as follows.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Element;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Node;
import org.jsoup.select.Elements;
import org.jsoup.select.NodeVisitor;

public class HtmlTest {

    public static String parseHtml( String str ) {
        org.jsoup.nodes.Document doc = Jsoup.parse(str);

        final List<String> wordList = new ArrayList<String>();

        doc.body().traverse(
            new NodeVisitor(){

                @Override
                public void head(Node arg0, int arg1) {
                    if(arg1 == 1)
                    {
                        //String value = Jsoup.parse(arg0.outerHtml()).text();
                        String value = arg0.outerHtml();
                        if(!wordList.contains(value))
                            wordList.add(arg0.outerHtml());

                    }

                }

                @Override
                public void tail(Node arg0, int arg1) {

                }
            }
        );


        for(String word: wordList)
        {
            System.out.println(word);
        }

        return "";
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        System.out.println(parseHtml( "We are <b><i>very</i></b><b>a</b>mused!\nThank you." ));
    }
}
```

The output must be looks like,

```
We are 
<b><i>very</i></b>
<b>a</b>
mused! Thank you.
```

***2. C# version***

Well, The source code of C# version is a litte bit different 
but the same process( with a little change needed).

This is my NodeVisitor version of code.

First parse the html contents.

```
Document doc = NSoupClient.Parse(str);
```

Second, select original sentence from 'body' tag.

```
doc.Select("body").Traverse(new TestNodeVisitor(wordList));
```

The complete code as follows.

```
using NSoup;
using NSoup.Nodes;
using NSoup.Select;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
namespace NSoupTest
{

    class Program
    {

        private class TestNodeVisitor : NodeVisitor
        {
            List<String> wordList;

            public TestNodeVisitor(List<String> wordList)
            {
                this.wordList = wordList;
            }

            public void Head(Node node, int depth)
            {
                if(depth == 1)
                {
                    String value = node.OuterHtml();

                    if(!wordList.Contains(value))
                        wordList.Add(value);
                }

            }

            public void Tail(Node node, int depth)
            {

            }
        }


        public static String parseHtml( String str ) {
            Document doc = NSoupClient.Parse(str);


            List<String> wordList 
                = new List<String>();

            doc.Select("body").Traverse(new TestNodeVisitor(wordList));


            foreach (String word in wordList)
            {

                Console.WriteLine(word);
            }

            return "";
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            try
            {
                parseHtml("We are <b><i>very</i></b><b>a</b>mused!\nThank you.");
            }
            catch (FileNotFoundException fe) {
                Console.WriteLine(fe.Message);
            }

        }
    }
}
```

The output also should be

```
We are
<b><i>very</i></b>
<b>a</b>
mused! Thank you.
```

You can find the NSoup library I used at this time(actually, not a official version 0.8.0) from the [site](https://github.com/Airstriker/GoogleImagesSearch/blob/master/bin/Debug/NSoup.dll).

The official NSoup site is [here](https://nsoup.codeplex.com/) but no visitor interface.

Then, you can use your own method to complete code.

I must tell you this is just an option for your goal.

Regard,

Comment: Hi, sorry i forgot to say that this is for c#.

Also the result must be as shown on my sample